# Which mobile framework to use?

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, titanium, extjs

I am a newbie for developing web-apps on android devices. I came across of number of mobile development frameworks(Sencha, Titanium, JQuery Mobile, etc) over the Internet and am kind of confused over which one should be used. Can anyone please guide me on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends if you want a browser based web app or a mobile app.
I have used jQuery mobile for mobile web sites an like it a lot. A lot of people also use jQuery mobile in conjunction with phonegap (http://phonegap.com/) to produce mobile apps.

So if you want to do a mobile web page I would look at using jQuery mobile or sencha touch.
If you want a full blown app without writing objective c or java then frameworks like Titanium and phonegap allow you to do this with javascript and html.
These frameworks generally expose os functionality through higher level javascript apis and you can write your code in html and js. Both Sencha and jQuery mobile work with phonegap.
I'd recommend deciding on if you want a native app or a mobile web site and then look into the various frameworks from there and try a few out to see which meet your needs.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what you need to do and your background. At least for me jQuery mobile still misses somes widgets which are cool and make your applications nice.

I find Sencha to be the most complete one, but it has its drawbacks since I dont really like the community because they are not very noob-friendly. Take a look at the forum and you'll see. There is just a bunch of Gurus with the willing to help others.

Also, it has a Object base so you'll find it easier if you know Java or any other Object based programming language.

Sencha is also 99% JavaScript based and doesnt work from markup, which is something sometimes annoying.

Anyway, I still recommend Sencha if you have the patience because you can do some really cool stuff. Specially with Sencha Charts.

If you dont have that much time, jQuery Mobile or the new Dojo framework seem to do the job pretty well.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest whatever you're strongest is if you need to get something out. If you have time to play or want to learn a new framework I would suggest whatever interests you the most. IMHO I like jQueryMobile as I am familiar with jQuery and it was very simple for me to pick up. All will have some limitations and perks

Answer (score 0):

My first choice is phonegap for iOS and android and second will be Titanium.